# Differentiability of convolution without compact support

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, convolution

Let $g \in C^1(\mathbb R), f, g, g' \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.
How do I then show $f * g$ is differentiable? Variations of this question have been asked where $g$ or $g'$ have compact support, but these assumption make it  easier since that implies boundedness due to continuity.

My work so far:
Compute
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(f * g)(x+h) - (f * g)(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) \frac{g(x+h-y) - g(x-y)}{h} dy.$$

Because of dominated convergence, we can swap the limits as we wish to if we are able to exhibit an integrable bound $H \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ with
$$|f(y) (g(x-y + 1/n)-g(x-y)) n| \le H(y)$$
for all $n$.
If you restrict yourself to $H : (-a,a) \to \mathbb R$, this easily follows by the mean value theorem, indeed you can choose $H$ constant in this case. However, $g'$ does not have to be bounded over $\mathbb R$, so there's no obvious way of recovering a similar result.

I also know $g$ is bounded due to the integrability of $g'$, but of course, that's not quite sufficient.

Any ideas? In particular, I'd like to avoid too much functional analysis, this is for a relatively basic analysis class.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Akira sure, anything that bounds $g'$ should work out due to the mean value theorem, but according to wikipedia and a couple other sources, integrability seems to be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption implies that $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R)$ and $g \in W^{1, 1} (\mathbb R)$. Then we can apply the following result from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*:

> **Lemma 8.4.** Let $\rho \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $v \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Then $\rho * v \in$ $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $(\rho * v)'=\rho * v'$.

Notice that a function in $W^{1, 1} (\mathbb R)$ is locally absolutely continuous and thus differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: Why is a downvote?

Comment: Maybe in addition to quoting the theorem, you could sketch the argument here so people without access to the book can see what's going on

Comment: @AlexOrtiz The book is freely available at https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7.

Comment: That's a nice point, though I think SpringerLink only gives access to people who are somehow actively affiliated with a university. If the argument is short, I don't see any downside of adding the sketch of the argument to your answer

Comment: @AlexOrtiz You can also download the book from https://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf.